# Adobe Animate HTML 5 Error when accessing internal library via external js script

Tags: javascript, java, actionscript-3, html5-canvas

Recently started learning Javascript and here is the problem
When trying to access the internal Adobe Animate library through an external JS script, it swears and writes an error
And if I write this script inside Adobe Animate it works fine, please help

```
let myBlue = new lib.blueShape;
exportRoot.addChild(myBlue);
let xPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()*700);
let yPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()*700);
myBlue.x = xPosition;
myBlue.y = yPosition;
root.push(myBlue);
```

t**hrows an error on -  let myBlue = new lib.blueShape;**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjcMy.jpg)

Comment: There is no Java here. It seems you have started learning Javascript, not Java. One good thing to learn is that they are two completely different languages.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

When using the new keyword you're calling a function which is the constructor of the object so you need to use parenthesis.

```
let myBlue = new lib.blueShape();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer to the point, well, it doesn’t help, I already found the answer to my question

Comment: @DeniSmith I suggest posting your solution as an answer to help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

In html file published by Animate you have code like this:

```
var comp=AdobeAn.getComposition("3AB147FF51228A35B6EEF42C65F44408");
var lib=comp.getLibrary();
```

You need to do the same in your JavaScript code, first get **lib** reference and then use it, it's not global by default.